# Grand Theft Auto V exited unexpectedly - Rockstar edition

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

Hi after downloading GTAV from the social club plus all the updates I am receiving the error "Grand Theft Auto V exited unexpectedly".

My Asus ROG G751JY specs are:

- Intel® Core™ i7 4860HQ /4710HQ Processor
- 24GB DDR3L RAM
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX980M 4GB GDDR5
- 1TB HDD 7200
- SSD With 256 GB RPM

I have tried the following none of which solve the issue

- Launching GTAVLauncher.exe as a shortcut with the -verify option
- Updating my Nvidia drivers to version 355.98
- Updating my realtek audio drivers
- Setting audio output to 44100hz 16bit
- Adjusting properties of GTAVLauncher.exe and GTA5.exe to run in Windows 8 compatbility mode (I'm running in Windows 10)
- Launching GTAVLauncher as administrator

I have attached a number of files to hopefully help see what the issue is

- Screenshot of the error

[image: crash message]

### Event viewer error

```
Faulting application name: GTA5.exe, version: 1.0.463.1, time stamp: 0x55e6c608
Faulting module name: GTA5.exe, version: 1.0.463.1, time stamp: 0x55e6c608
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000011ff1f4
Faulting process ID: 0x1dd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0f63955a1e3fe
Faulting application path: e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe
Faulting module path: e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe
Report ID: 02af2857-b052-409e-8d19-912e4dbd316a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

### GTA V launcher log info

```
[2015-09-23 20:19:48.973] [DISPLAY] Using DPI 96
[2015-09-23 20:19:49.103] [DISPLAY] File version 10000:1cf0001 (for e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe)
[2015-09-23 20:19:49.196] [DISPLAY] File version 10001:60005 (for C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Social Club\socialclub.dll)
[2015-09-23 20:19:49.286] [DISPLAY] File version 10000:1b80002 (for E:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTAVLauncher.exe)
[2015-09-23 20:19:49.306] [DISPLAY] Version: 1.0.231.0|1.0.463.1|1.1.6.5|1.0.440.2|FFP
[2015-09-23 20:19:49.806] [DISPLAY] OS version: Major: 6, Minor: 2, Build: 9200, Platform: 2
[2015-09-23 20:19:50.819] [DISPLAY] File version 10000:1cf0001 (for e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe)
[2015-09-23 20:19:51.276] [DISPLAY] Opened options file.
[2015-09-23 20:19:51.647] [DISPLAY] File version 10001:60005 (for C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Social Club\socialclub.dll)
[2015-09-23 20:19:51.707] [DISPLAY] Social Club initializing...
[2015-09-23 20:19:52.427] [DISPLAY] Attempting to create device...
[2015-09-23 20:19:52.434] [DISPLAY] Attempting to initialise DX9 COM object...
[2015-09-23 20:19:52.454] [DISPLAY] Window size: 690 x 496
[2015-09-23 20:19:52.486] [DISPLAY] Successfully created DX Device!
[2015-09-23 20:19:58.636] [DISPLAY] Geo: GB
[2015-09-23 20:20:03.458] [DISPLAY] File version 10000:1cf0001 (for e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe)
[2015-09-23 20:20:14.066] [DISPLAY] In-place download is up-to-date.
[2015-09-23 20:20:14.191] [DISPLAY] Launching game...
[2015-09-23 20:20:14.198] [DISPLAY] (path: e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe cmdline: "e:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe")
[2015-09-23 20:20:28.354] [WARNING] Device lost.
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.954] [DISPLAY] Game exited with code 0xff
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.954] [ ERROR ] Unable to stat out-file!
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.959] [ ERROR ] ************************************************** **********************
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.959] [ ERROR ] * Setting error condition
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.960] [ ERROR ] * Category: 1 (ERROR_CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.960] [ ERROR ] * Code: 107 (LAUNCHER_ERR_GAME_CRASHED)
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.960] [ ERROR ] * Extra: 
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.960] [ ERROR ] * Localised: Launcher error. Code: 107 
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.960] [ ERROR ] ************************************************** **********************
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.966] [ ERROR ] Unable to read out-file!
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.971] [ ERROR ] ************************************************** **********************
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.971] [ ERROR ] * Setting error condition
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.971] [ ERROR ] * Category: 5 (ERROR_CATEGORY_EXIT_CODE)
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.972] [ ERROR ] * Code: 255 (ff)
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.972] [ ERROR ] * Extra: 
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.972] [ ERROR ] * Localised: Grand Theft Auto V exited unexpectedly. 

Please click Retry below to enter the game again, or click Safe Mode to launch the game with reduced graphics settings. 

If you continue to have problems playing the game, please contact Rockstar Games Customer Service at http://support.rockstargames.com
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.972] [ ERROR ] ************************************************** **********************
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.979] [DISPLAY] Reset succeeded.
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.981] [ ERROR ] Exit code 0xff indicates a game crash (unknown cause)
[2015-09-23 20:20:32.994] [ ERROR ] Unable to clear in-file and out-file!
[2015-09-23 20:20:39.671] [DISPLAY] Uninitializing.
```

Comment: did you try the safe mode?

Comment: yes same issue!

Comment: Could you please add your pc specifications?

Comment: ok I've done that now, it more than meets the requirements

Comment: Unless this happens to be a common error *with* known solution, I doubt there is anything we can do. At least I couldn't find anything helpful from the logs. I suggest contacting RockStart support.

Comment: I feared as much :(, any idea what their response time is usually like?

Comment: @PaulStatham It looks to me like you installed GTA5 on drive 'e'. This may be the issue. I have had some games which failed to run if the were not on drive 'C'

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same error (although my game version differs a little bit: 1.0.573.1).
For me, it helped to delete the GTA5.exe from the game directory, start the launcher and let it redownload the exe.

Comment: it was fixed in the end by a patch, so for me at least this was a bug

Comment: I guess your patch updated your gta5.exe to a newer version (that would also be a logic explanation why my version is higher than yours)